# A collection of real numbers sets is called proper, if it is possible to choose numbers from every set such that every 3 numbers suffice A+B $\neq$ C

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A proper collection is defined as a collection of real numbers sets, which suffice that it is possible to choose 1 element from each set in the collection (it is possible to choose the same number if it appears in different sets), such that every triplet from the chosen numbers holds that $a + b \neq c$.

The first part of the question is to prove that if a collection S which contains **only** finite sets, suffice that for every finite subset $S'\subset S$ is a proper set, then $S$ is a proper collection.

I used the compactness theorem for predicate calculus to prove it.

The second part, asking whether the first part stays true without the demands for $S$ to contain only finite sets?

I was trying to play with the set of all pythagorean triplets to create a collection which will force the choosing process to end with a triplet $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. But it didn't work for me.

Second thought was to define $S'$ in which we replace all the infinite sets $A_{\alpha} \in S$ with all their finite subsets. Then from the first part $S'$ is a proper set and show that if $S'$ is proper then $S$ is proper too.

Comment: I think the definition of "proper" is unclear.  In any case, it should not just be defined in the header.  The notion is that you make a single choice (one element from each collection) and then require that your condition hold across all triplets from the collection?  Or are you asking that the set of values you have chosen satisfy the condition without reference to the sets?  For example, suppose I choose $0$ from one of my sets.  Is $0+0=0$ a disproof of properness?

Comment: @lulu I added a description, is it better now? and for your example if 0 appears in 3 different sets, and a choose must include 3 appearance of 0's then 0 + 0 = 0 will disproof properness .

Comment: Yes, that's clearer.  Thanks.